# How can I make rects from JSON?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm doing a project to learn d3 visualization
and I'm stack recs aren't appearing. Could you help me?

I tried to put a simple array for data and it worked, I could only flip y,
but with this JSON data. nothing works

https://codepen.io/DeanWinchester88/pen/XWgjjeW

```
let dataSet;
let data;
function readTextFile(file, callback) {
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    rawFile.open("GET", file, true);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (rawFile.readyState === 4 && rawFile.status == "200") {
            callback(rawFile.responseText);
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);
}
//usage: 
readTextFile("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/GDP-data.json", function(text){
    data = JSON.parse(text);
      dataSet = data["data"]
    console.log(dataSet);
});

const w = 700;
const h = 500;

const svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width",w)
  .attr("heigth",h)
  .attr("style", "outline: thin solid red;");

svg.selectAll("rect")
  .data(dataSet)
  .enter()
       .append("rect")
       .attr("x", (d,i) => d[1][i]+ 10)
       .attr("y", (d, i) => 0 )
       .attr("width", 25)
       .attr("height", (d, i) => d[1] /2 )
       .attr("fill", "navy")
       .attr("class", "bar")
       .append("title")
       .text((d) => d)

  svg.selectAll("text")
       .data(dataSet)
       .enter()
       .append("text")
       .text((d) => d)
       .attr("x", (d, i) => i * 30 +10)
       .attr("y", (d, i) => 15)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `XMLHttpRequest` is asynchronous and you are defining the d3 logic outside of the callback passed to `readTextFile`. The easiest solution would be to include the d3 logic inside of the callback:

```js
readTextFile("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/GDP-data.json", function(text){
    data = JSON.parse(text);
      dataSet = data["data"]
    console.log(dataSet);
    // Add d3 logic here
    const w = 700;
const h = 500;

const svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width",w)
  .attr("heigth",h)
  .attr("style", "outline: thin solid red;");

svg.selectAll("rect")
  .data(dataSet)
  .enter()
       .append("rect")
        // Changed this line to remove the [i]
       .attr("x", (d,i) => d[1] + 10)
       .attr("y", (d, i) => 0 )
       .attr("width", 25)
       .attr("height", (d, i) => d[1] /2 )
       .attr("fill", "navy")
       .attr("class", "bar")
       .append("title")
       .text((d) => d)

  svg.selectAll("text")
       .data(dataSet)
       .enter()
       .append("text")
       .text((d) => d)
       .attr("x", (d, i) => i * 30 +10)
       .attr("y", (d, i) => 15)

});
```

To avoid callback you could wrap the response to `readTextFile` in a `Promise` and then use `async/await` to `dataSet = await readTextFile(...)`.

Comment: gosh u are great.thank you. As for avoiding callback, i just startd d3 api at freecodecamp couple days ago so it's too high level for me. and thanks

Comment: No problem. Have fun with d3, its a great library.